# Reverse hangman #12

Tags: word-problem, letters

Put in an "H", and you'll find that not many actually chase it.

Put in a "C", this free and you're clean.

Put in a "P", looks like you got it dirty.

Put in an "L", it's small, but some things go in just fine.

The answer should be in the form

> _pple

followed by an explanation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> S_OT

H

> SHOT: Not many people use chasers when drinking shots?

C

> SCOT: "Scot free" means you're safe (clean)

P

> SPOT: Got a stain

L

> SLOT: Like a coin slot

Comment: So fast, that's right. I'll accept it later, just to follow the rules.

Answer (score 5):

**Attempt2**

Another possibility is:

> _ast

H

> Hast: archaic second person singular present of have. Not used must or chased.

C

> Cast: You cast type1 to type2. Once casting (forceful moulding or reshaping) is free, object is clean.

P

> Past: Not many people are satisfied with their past

L

> Last: Last but not the least. Happy ending.

---

I think the answer is:

> _atch

H

> Hatch: Not sure

C

> Catch: Once free after being caught, and your are free

P

> Patch: patching with cloth to fix something actually looks ugly

L

> Latch: Even small latches are good to hold big doors

Comment: A clever answer, but not quite what I had in mind.